# Ionic with "custom" sass template

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, sass, apk, material-components

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to "convert/wrap" a sass project (actually a website builed with material.io web components) to apk.
I tried with Ionic, but as far as I understand it support just Angular and React, and with Cordova but it doesn't support scss files.
Tried to Google it but I didn't find nothing.

Do somebody knows anything to achieve this?

Edit:
In reply to user9088454

Yes, I copied the site (If I run it with npm it works from the browser) on the src folder of Ionic project but when I launch a "ionic cordova emulate android" to emulate the app on the Android Emulator I receive this error:

An unhandled exception occurred: error TS18003: No inputs were found in config file 'C:/Users/william.manzato/Wamp/ionic-ncr/tsconfig.app.json'. Specified 'include' paths were '["src/**/*.ts"]' and 'exclude' paths were '["src/test.ts","src/***/.spec.ts"]'.

See "C:\Users\WILLIA~1.MAN\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-YhTcaA\angular-errors.log" for further details.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.

Ionic is still searching for Angular.

Comment: Did you try in ionic? got error? any code sample?

Comment: can you provide a reproducible code sample? and which version of ionic are you using? As far as I know, ionic supports sass; the issue might be caused by something else